# Linked Lists (Deletion and Searching)

Tags: c++, linked-list

The following pseudo-code deletes a node from the linked list.

```
void list::erase()//Deletes a node
{
cout<< "Enter a position: ";
cin>> pos;
if(pos==1)
{
   current=head;
   head=head->ptr;
}
else
{
   current=head;
   for(i=0; i<pos-1; i++)
   {        
       temp=current;
       current=current->ptr;
   }
       temp->ptr=current->ptr;
}
cout<< "Erased string: " << current->content<<"\t";

current=head;
while(current!=NULL)
{
    cout<<current->content<<"\t";
    current=current->ptr;
}
}
```

I need to display a message in case I delete a string that is not in the list: There is no such string. What should I do?

The following pseudo-code searches a node in the linked list.

```
void list::search()//Searches a node
{
    char str[50];
    cout<<"Enter a string: ";
    cin>> str;
    current=head;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        pos++;
        if(!strcmp(current->content, str))
        {
            cout<< "Found at "<<pos;
        }
            current=current->ptr;
    }
}
```

If I search for a *string* that is **not** in the *list* and display a *message* accordingly: There is no such string. What should I do? Please help.

Comment: what exactly is not working here? your search function looks ok except you are missing the message in case the string is not found.

Comment: @Pandrei For example: In the list: 1  2  3  4, if I search for 5 then message gets displayed as: Not found. (4 times (until while loop gets executed n times))

Comment: put a return after "Fount at" and put a cout <<"string not found" after the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before entering the `while loop` set a variable `found= false`. You change the value of the variable only when you find the string you are looking for, and you do the printing after the while:

```
found = false;
while(current!=NULL)
{
    pos++;
    if(!strcmp(current->content, str))
    {
       found = true;
       break;
    }
    current=current->ptr;
}
if (found)
  cout<< "Found at "<<pos;
else
   cout<< "Not Found";
```

Comment: And what can I do in case of deletion?

Comment: I don't the question about delete; what do you mean delete a string that is not in the list? if it's not in the list how can you delete it?